# Knowing the time of arrival to point X

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have a bus that does `A-------X------------------------B`

it goes at 10 hours from A, having:

Speed at A `sA = 10 m/s`
constant acceleration `a = -0,5 m/s2`

At what hour it will be at X, knowing the distance AX `dAX = 50m` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being $s = \frac{a}{2} t^2 + v t + s_0$ you might be able to work something out.